# Twill and Self-Signed Certificates

Tags: python, ssl, self-signed, twill

I've been using Twill under Python for a long time now, and somehow, I never managed to run into this before.

If you point Twill at a page using a Self-Signed certificate, it errors out, like this:

```
BrowserStateError: can't fetch relative reference: not viewing any document

In [4]: b.go("https://page")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
BrowserStateError                         Traceback (most recent call la
<ipython-input-4-ff59517ca246> in <module>()
----> 1 b.go("https://page")

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twill/browser.pyc in go(self, url)
    120             print>>OUT, '==> at', self.get_url()
    121         else:
--> 122             raise BrowserStateError("cannot go to '%s'" % (url,))
    123 
    124     def reload(self):

BrowserStateError: cannot go to 'https://page'
```

Both non encrypted pages, and pages with working certs, all work just fine.  Is there a way to get Twill to power through this?